# Why SQL Express database is 4 times bigger than SQL CE counterpart?

Tags: sql-server

I have been using SQL CE as my database system, but for further functionality I am now switching to SQL Express. While running the first test, I found that the SQL Express 2005 database reached 4GB within one day, whereas a SQL CE database with similar size of data is only around 1GB.

I later tested in another system with SQL Express 2008, where the database size was still bigger than the CE version, but not as much as the above.

I tried shrinking database using SQL Management Studio, but it only reduced from 4096mb to 4095.55mb. I have learned that SQL Express databases requires extra space for performing its operations, but I don't think that should be 4 times and in one day. What should I look for?

Comment: Did you checked your database growth settings?

Comment: What RECOVERY MODE do you have your SQL Server Express database in? If it's in FULL mode, it will log all transactions and everything - that can easily reach 4 GB in a day. You could switch to SIMPLE recovery mode to slow that down. SQL CE doesn't have any of those sophisticated server-based logging mechanism and thus uses a lot less disk space

Answer (score 0):

Check the the minimum size you specified when you create your databases.Check your database growth settings etc.minimum size of a database is  specified when the database was originally created, or the last  size set by using a file-size-changing operation, such as DBCC SHRINKFILE. For example, if a database was originally created with a size of 4GB and grew to 4.1 GB, the smallest size the database could be reduced to is 4GB, even if all the data in the database has been deleted.